# Which division should I choose for integer rings: rounded or truncated?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, divisibility, integers, programming

I am coding a library with other math students like me where we play around with the conceps we are learning in *Algebra I* course. You can find it on GitHub: [Algebra_I](https://github.com/pabloasenjo3/Algebra_I)

Currently I am building a class (an object, a piece of code so to speak) to represent quadratic integer rings ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_integer#Quadratic_integer_rings)) and I want to implement  the division between elements of such rings. The problem is there is no unique division in this case, so I'll have to stick with one.

Let's start with this example: [Example division picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LtqK.png)

And another, simple integer example: 3 / 5

- One option would be to perform truncated integer divisions:

  [Truncated division picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EginH.png)

  This way the quotient would be **0 + 0i = o** and the remainder,
  **-1 + 11i**. As for the simple integer example, the quotient would be **0** and the remainder, **3**.

  PROS: It's intuitive for coders and what users (classmates) might expect.
- The other option I have come up with would be to perform rounded
  integer divisions:

  [Rounded division picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5dS8.png)

  This way the quotient would be **0 + i** and the remainder, **9 +
  i**. As for the simple integer example, the quotient would be **1**
  and the remainder, **-2**.

  PROS: The remainders are the smallest possible (their norms are).

  CONS: Its integer equivalent is non euclidean (negative
  remainders).

Which of these two divisions makes more sense or is more useful? Can you come up with a better option?

Thanks beforehand and Happy New Year :).

Comment: Why would you only have one rounding mode?  Wouldn't it be more useful to follow the C/C++ model of having [user-settable rounding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/FE_round)?  Then you would let the user of your object decide how rounding should work to support whatever they are doing with your object.

Comment: @EricTowers But that implies working with floating point variables. Wouldn't precision errors occur then?

Comment: I did not say to coerce to floating point.  I said to give your users the choice of which rounding method to use.

Comment: @EricTowers Sounds interesting. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Add 0.5 to your total, then truncate. ;)

Comment: In the ring of Gaussian integers, for the purposes of Euclidean algorithm, you really want to round the real and imaginary parts to the nearest integers. Otherwise the remainder may be larger (in terms of absolute value) than the element you divide with. Anyway, that cannot be fulfilled in all quadratic integer rings anyway. So I don't know if you find this point of view pressing at all :-)

Comment: @shawn_halayka Thanks!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks!